# How Do I Convert a Picture into a Sha256 Hash Python

Tags: python

Is it possible to input a picture into the sha256 feature of hashlib and have it spit out a hash using Python?

Comment: Excepts of the rather trivial part where the image has to be read in, that is like the the primary function of the haslib. Did you expect it to work differently?

Comment: I honestly do not know the limits of it seeing as I only found out about it today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this helps? [Link](https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/python/how-to-calculate-sha256-hash-of-a-file-in-python.html)

You have to import hashlib, open the file, and then calculate the hash.

```
import hashlib

filename = "Filepath to image file.png"
with open(filename,"rb") as f:
    bytes = f.read() # read entire file as bytes
    readable_hash = hashlib.sha256(bytes).hexdigest();
    print(readable_hash)
```

Comment: How will Python know where the file is?

Comment: set the filename to be the filepath of the image you want calculate the hash of (relative path of the image). "/image.png" will presume the image is called 'image.png' and it's inside the directory of the script you are running.

Comment: Do not name the `f.read()` as `bytes` by the way, because it is a built-in method, so declaring variables after them is not allowed and will cause errors in the code. Just a  small note if you still face errors in your code.